# Will Kafka Stream lose state if node crashed and old topic messages discarded due to retention?

Tags: apache-kafka, state, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

By default, kafka stream uses RocksDB, a fast local KV storage, as its state store. My question is, will kafka stream lose state if node crashed and those topic messages to replay state is discarded due to kafka retention happened (so it can’t replay messages from the very beginning) ? Does it mean those old state lost in such case? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Streams backs RocksDB store in ["changelog topics" in Kafka](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Internal+Data+Management). Those changelog topics are configured with log compaction enabled. Thus, state is never be lost.